# RuntimeError: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of dimension: 1

Tags: python, pytorch

I have read other people's questions for similar issues, but can't figure it out in my case. My code is below, how do I fix this? Thank you.

```
data = ImageFolder(data_dir, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224,224)),transforms.ToTensor()]))

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=3600,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

dataiter = iter(trainloader)
x_train, y_train = dataiter.next()

print(x_train.size())
print(y_train.size())
```

torch.Size([3600, 3, 224, 224])

torch.Size([3600])

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # here we set up the tensors......
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(224, 12)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(12, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        # here we define the (forward) computational graph,
        # in terms of the tensors, and elt-wise non-linearities
        x = F.relu(self.layer1(x))
        x = self.layer2(x)
        return x

net = Net()
y = net.forward(x_train)
lossFn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() 
loss = lossFn(y, y_train)
print(loss)
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input to the network is a 2D image. That is a tensor with 4 dimensions: batch, channel, height and width.
However, you treat the 2D input as a 1D signal by applying `nn.Linear` layers to its width dimension only, resulting with an output of shape batch*channel*height*output_dim. In contrast, the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` expects only one output vector per target label.

You need to change your `Net` to properly process images into a *single* vector of predictions.

You can checkout milestone image classification architectures [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html).

Comment: would you mind please having a look at my recent post too? @Shai